# Raster Calculator - Error 000539: Error running expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I'm trying to simply combine 5 different rasters in raster calculator to do a site suitability analysis using this map algebra expression:

```
"bo_reclasstemph3" + "bo_reclassph" + "bo_raster_precip" + "bo_raster_elevation" + "bo_raster_soiltext"
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

> Messages
>       Executing: RasterCalculator ""Reclass_ph3" + "Reclass_annualmintemp" + "Raster_precipitation" +
>   "Raster_soiltexture" + "Raster_elevat""
>   T:\Barnett_GIS_Spring18\Agroforestry\California_Agroforestry.gdb\final1_plzwork
>       Start Time: Wed May 09 15:22:46 2018
>       Raster(r"Reclass_ph3") + Raster(r"Reclass_annualmintemp") + Raster(r"Raster_precipitation") + Raster(r"Raster_soiltexture") +
>   Raster(r"Raster_elevat")
>       ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "", line 5, in rcexec
>         File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4329, in
>   Plus
>           in_raster_or_constant2)
>         File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
>           result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4326, in
>   Wrapper
>           ["Plus", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
>       RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
>
> ```
> Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
> Failed at Wed May 09 15:22:46 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.08 seconds)
> ```

The day before I completed the same process with the same data but different rankings and it worked:

[image: Working raster calculator]

Comment: I tried it on a different computer and had the same problem. Also I retried the same raster calculator query on the rasters that worked before and they no longer work... I am getting the same error message. So something must have happened in between then and now...

Comment: Please provide all error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: Where is your code? That would be quite helpful. Are you sure you set your workspace correctly so that the rasters can be found? Try creating each raster object one by one then sum the objects, without code it's hard to explain further. Are all the rasters in the same spatial reference, cell type and extent?

Comment: I'm just trying to do a simple addition map algebra expression and I added it above so you can see. I have set the workspaces to the correct geodatabase but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: a)  cell statistics  (SUM) will do the same thing b) check extent settings c) try output to GRID stored in folder/